# Adding properties/more data to GeoJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, gis

I have a GeoJson of U.S. Counties courtesy of the Internet. I'm making a visualization around county data.

This is the data structure. Is there a way I can add more properties to it without copying and pasting into each?

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DATA": 25.0, "COUNTY": "27049", "NAME": "Goodhue", "POPULATION": 46183.0, "F18_POP_20": 32425.0, "F18_POP": 35233.0, "H18_POP": 745.0, "NH18_WHT": 33501.0, "NH18_DOJ_B": 279.0, "NH18_DOJ_I": 427.0, "NH18_DOJ_A": 210.0, "NH18_DOJ_H": 23.0, "NH18_DOJ_O": 19.0, "NH18_DOJ_1": 29.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ SVG DATA ] ] } }, 

{ "type": "Feature", ........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set properties of a JavaScript object in a couple of different ways

```
obj.property = value
```

or

```
obj['property'] = value;
```

Although on second glance it looks like your is an unparsed JSON file, in which case you want to call JSON.parse() on the string first.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```